# m3u8 Live streaming application

Tags: android, streaming, live

Do i have to use a plug in to play TV Video Live streaming(.m3u8) in android application??

I'm using Surface and Media Player to show it.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Live Streaming is supported since API Level 11, as long as your app is targeting to run on GingerBread (API Level 11), You don't need anything else to play the video.

If your app is targeting to run on a older Android system (2.2 or 2.1), there are some third party framework that help you fill the gap, check out [Vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/).